# How to refresh Cucumber Output file in IntelliJ while using multiple feature files?

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am using the BDD framework using Cucumber,

There are multiple feature files.

But am not able to get the output in the HTML file. (However, I can see the output in my console. )

Where am going wrong? How to keep this file(CucmberExtentReport.html) updated in IntelliJ IDEA?

Screenshot of the folders:
[image]

Am getting the HTML output only on running the whole configuration from here [image]

But I want to run a single feature file and see the output which IntelliJ is not updating...

I am running single feature by clicking run like this: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure I got the problem correctly. Could you provide a couple of screenshots showing the expected/actual result? Try to move your HTML file to the [sources root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#configure-folders).

Comment: @EgorKlepikov When i am running the whole configuration am getting HTML output in the mentioned folder, but when am right-clicking on particular feature file and then running it, the HTML doesn't get updated.

Comment: I have added some more info, pls see if it helps... maybe am missing some config or setting.

Comment: If possible please upload your project at https://uploads.jetbrains.com so that I could check the configuration. (do not forget to specify the UploadID)